# Is it just me, or do smartphone cameras not have any chromatic aberations at all?

Tags: color, artifacts, smartphone, camera, chromatic-aberration

To this day I have failed to spot any color artifacts in smartphone photos. Either Nokia N8 phone on a camera or my old Vibe P1 Turbo and even the G7102 I have (Which has glare towards the edges)

Is it just me? How does new cameras deal with it? Do they have onboard RAW to JPEG conversion with preset options, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A factor which might affect it: the diffraction is so huge on these tiny sensors and the cheap lenses may not be sharp, so it might be the case the image is not sharp enough for you to see the chromatic aberration! Chromatic aberration can be only seen if the image is otherwise sharp.

I'm far from certain this is the only reason for that (it might be the case that whatever little chromatic aberration there is that exceeds the diffraction and other sources of non-sharpness is removed by sophisticated algorithms processing the raw data from the sensor). But it can be **a** reason.

I think the combination of lack of sharpness otherwise due to diffraction / poor non-sharp lens and algorithms might explain all of what you're seeing.

**Edit:** @DeltaOscarUniform calculated that unless the megapixel count is excessive, the diffraction should be nonexistent due to the relatively small F-number of F2.8 (typical). Yet, the other sources of lack of sharpness prevail. However, a 12 megapixel phone camera still has half of the pixels of a 24 megapixel DSLR/mirrorless, so the low megapixel could could be (part of) an explanation.

Comment: Calculating diffractions with megapixel and sensor size and the F value. There should be no diffraction. 12 Meg with 1/2.3 and typical F2.8 doesnt have diffraction at least according to the here https://www.cambridgeincolour.com/tutorials/diffraction-photography.htm

Comment: @DeltaOscarUniform Thanks for the information! However, the lens may not be otherwise sharp enough...

Answer (score 7):

It is likely because chromatic aberrations are easy to fix on a fixed focal length, and fixed focus lens. And whatever remains is hidden by the heavy-handed post-processing that occurs.

Comment: Fixed focus? Are you sure? I think most smartphones do not have a fixed focus lens anymore.